# How to get specific value from mongodb in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get double digit number from mongodb but not able to get.I am getting 1 to 9 only after that i am not able to get more then 9.I do not know why it is not fetching the value from mongodb.

i am trying to get latest inserted record's pid but more then 9 am not able to get it.

My database:mongodb

```
{
"name":"ssk",
"p_id" : "CS9"
},
{
"name":"ssk",
"p_id" : "CS10"
}
```

Node:
data.controller.js:

```
module.exports.insertData = async(req, res, next) => {
var Product = mongoose.model(req.query.collectionName); 
var getProductId;
var checkProductId;
var getFandLa =  "CS";
var productId = await Product.findOne().sort({ p_id: -1 }).limit(1);
 //productId is always getting single value like CS9..Why?
    checkProductId = productId.p_id;
    var g = checkProductId.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');  
    var i = g;
    var j = Number(i);
    var j = ++j; 
    console.log("J=" + j); 
    getProductId = getFandLa + j;

}
```

Comment: With limit(1) you only get one record

Comment: `"CS9".localeCompare("CS10") === 1`

Comment: I am not able to get latest record's pid on each api call

Comment: @salesh: How can i get latest record on each api call? you haveany solution?

Comment: @VimalaK I can see that database is having field as "pid" and in code there is "p_id". Why is that? Shouldn't that be "pid" too?

Comment: @DeekshithHegde: updated ..now you can check

Comment: So you are getting one single record everytime. What do you need here? Also If you need a latest record then it's better to sort it based on timestamp(updatedAt). Why sort based on p_id?

Comment: @DeekshithHegde: Getting confuse..So can you update my code?

Comment: var productId = await Product.find({}).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1); Use this to fetch the lastest record

Comment: @DeekshithHegde: In the latest record how to get the p_id?

Comment: @DeekshithHegde: productId.p_id  getting undefined

Comment: productId[0].p_id . Try this. If you want productId.p_id this to be accessible then you can use findOne instead of find.

Comment: @DeekshithHegde: Working perfectly..Thank you so much.

Comment: @VimalaK Posted it in the answer as well. You can upvote and accept the answer if that has helped you solving your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get lastest record you can sort it based on "_id" instead and limit results to 1.
The following should work

```
var productId = await Product.find({}).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1)
```

You can also use findOne instead of find here